# Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu on Mac, without macOS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, macbook-air

Can you tell me How to dual boot windows and Ubuntu on macbook air 2017. I tried but I can't boot into windows after installing Linux. I don't want to use macOS

Comment: [Rescatux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix/921722#921722) is able to repair the Windows bootloader in a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot. Rescatux can boot on a Mac, but I don't know if it would work in this case. Maybe someone else will post a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using boot-repair to try and find the other OS. From Ubuntu or a LiveUSB, do this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Go through the steps it shows and it should bring you to a fully functional dualboot system